# what is the difference between gpuArray.ones and ones('gpuArray')?

Tags: matlab

what is the difference between gpuArray.ones(10,10) and ones(10,10,'gpuArray') ?

ref: https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/gpuarray_object.html

Comment: Historical note - the static method `gpuArray.ones` was available before the other syntax. It wouldn't have been necessary to introduce the static method if it had been possible to implement the other syntax at the time. New code should prefer `ones(...,'gpuArray')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same.

`ones` is a method of `gpuArray` among others - as you saw in the documentation you posted.

However, the function also called `ones` (which happens to have the same name as the `ones` `gpuArray` method) does the same thing when `'gpuArray'` is passed as the `'arraytype'` argument.

In short it depends on your taste.

Note: avoid doing `gpuArray(ones(10,10));` as that will create the GPU array on the host memory and then transfer it to the GPU over the PCIe - which is a lot slower than just creating it on the GPU with one of the methods you posted.

Comment: Thank you very much! I wonder why there are differences between eye and speye in that document? I mean, why there is no speye(m, n, ‘gpuArray’) ?

Comment: speye makes a sparse type identity matrix while eye makes a full idenity matrix. Check out the documentation for differences between sparse and full data types. I'm not sure why you there is no speye(m,n,'gpuArray') but sparse array functionality was not always available for GPU with matlab. It may be that they have not updated the speye() function yet. In any case, the gpuArray.methods will contain all the up-to-date capabilities - depending on your version of matlab.